# PHP Form update without logout

Tags: php, mysql, session

As i am newbie to PHP kindly pardon me if i looks silly ,

I created a form in php , while i do the update part of the form the update reflects in db whereas in the form it still shows the same old value . i tried refresh and force refresh but nothing changes .

Whereas if i logout and login again , the form shows the updated value .

I tried using `die();` after `mysql_close($link);` but it logs out the session and needs to re-login .

Kindly help me on viewing the changes while i am still inside the login .

**My code is as follows :**

```
<?php
         if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

            $name_a = $_POST['name'];
            $email_a = $_POST['email'];
            $pass_a = $_POST['password'];

            $sql = "UPDATE admin SET a_name = '$name_a', a_email = '$email_a', password = '$pass_a' where aid='$update_id' ";
            $retval = mysql_query($sql,$link);

            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            echo "Updated data successfully\n";

            mysql_close($link);

         }else {
            ?>
 <!-- Widget: user widget style 1 -->
          <div class="box box-widget widget-user-2">
            <!-- Add the bg color to the header using any of the bg-* classes -->
            <div class="widget-user-header bg-yellow">
              <div class="widget-user-image">
                 <?php echo '<img src="' . $img . '" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">'; ?>
              </div>
              <!-- /.widget-user-image -->
              <h3 class="widget-user-username"><?php echo "$name"; ?></h3>
              <h5 class="widget-user-desc"><?php echo "$role"; ?></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer no-padding">
              <form role="form" method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
              <div class="box-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputName1">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" name="name" value="<?php echo "$name"; ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="email" value="<?php echo "$email"; ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="password" value="<?php echo "$password"; ?>">
                </div>


              </div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->

              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="update" id="update"  class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.widget-user -->
      <?php
         }
      ?>
```

Comment: some code of your program please.

Comment: show code, it will help to find problem

Comment: @FrayneKonok Code added

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya Code added

Comment: after update data you have to select again

Comment: Fro where `$name`, `$img` come from???

Comment: @FrayneKonok thats from header.php which i included as require_once in the code

Comment: your header file in is the top of the page but your update query after the header.php file, so the form gives you the old value. Try to change the structure of your code.

Comment: @RajaGopal if possible try to include the `header.php` file inside the `else` portion.

Comment: have you using the session_start() on the top of this page?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya That solved the issue . Thanks a lot mate . Missing Select is the issue as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DivyeshSavaliya mentioned in the comment the issue is ,

I didn't Used Select query after update . Once done that the issue solved

The new working code is

```
<?php
         if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

            $name_a = $_POST['name'];
            $email_a = $_POST['email'];
            $pass_a = $_POST['password'];

            $sql = "UPDATE admin SET a_name = '$name_a', a_email = '$email_a', password = '$pass_a' where aid='$update_id' ";
            $retval = mysql_query($sql,$link);

            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
            }



         } 


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where aid='$update_id' ",$link);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        $name = $row['a_name'];
        $email = $row['a_email'];
        $password = $row['password'];

    }
     mysql_close($link);
            ?>
```

Thanks to @DivyeshSavaliya

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$name = '';
$email = '';
$password = '';
$update_id = '';
//$img = '';
//$role = '';
//$link = null;

if(
isset($_POST['update']) &&
isset($_POST['id']) &&
isset($_POST['name']) &&
isset($_POST['email']) &&
isset($_POST['password'])
) {
    $update_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $sql = 'UPDATE admin SET a_name = \'' . $name . '\', a_email = \'' . $email . '\', password = \'' . $password . '\' WHERE aid = \'' . $update_id . '\'';
    $result = @mysql_query($sql, $link);

    if(!$result)
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error($link));

    echo 'Updated data successfully', "\n";
}
elseif(isset($_GET['id'][0])) {
    $update_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $sql = 'SELECT a_name,a_email,a_password FROM admin WHERE aid = \'' . $update_id . '\'';

    $result = @mysql_query($sql, $link);
    if($result) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $name = $result[0];
        $email = $result[1];
        $password = $result[2];
    }
    else {
        echo 'Could not find the id.' . "\n";
        $update_id = '';
    }
}

unset($result);

if(isset($update_id[0])) { 
    mysql_close($link); 
?>
 <!-- Widget: user widget style 1 -->
<div class="box box-widget widget-user-2">
    <!-- Add the bg color to the header using any of the bg-* classes -->
    <div class="widget-user-header bg-yellow">
        <div class="widget-user-image">
            <img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($img); ?>" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <!-- /.widget-user-image -->
        <h3 class="widget-user-username"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?></h3>
        <h5 class="widget-user-desc"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($role); ?></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer no-padding">
        <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($update_id); ?>">
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputName1">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="password" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($password); ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->

            <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="update" id="update" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.widget-user -->
<?php } 
else {
    $sql = 'SELECT aid,a_name FROM admin';
    $result = @mysql_query($sql, $link);

    if($result) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<a href="?id=' . $row['aid'] . '">' . $row['a_name'] . '</a><br />' . "\n";
        }
    }
    mysql_close($link);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SOLUTION   
    1) use the updated value like $name_a instead of $name because $name_a contain updated value and $name contain old value 
   2) reload page after update and get new value from database on page load and store that value in $name , $email etc variable (if new data update successfully in database then only you get new value )
   3) if You store your data in session or cookie then update session and cookie value also when you update in database
```